# How do I get the CKEditor Styles plugin to wrap a text selection?

Tags: ckeditor

Check out the regular demo. Select a piece of text and change the style. The whole block changes, but I would like only the selected text to take on the new style.

http://ckeditor.com/demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you tried the block styles. Try the inline styles, like marker, which should do exactly what you want.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to achieve "inline styling" on a block element? So if I select the text "my" in <p>this is my text</p> and click the style for an H3, then I get this result: <p>this is</p><h3>my</h3><p>text</p>.

Comment: Not really, how would the code know when you want to convert the P element and when to break it? One solution to that use case might be to move the caret to `<p>this is |my text</p>` --> press enter --> move caret to `<p>this is </p><p>my| text</p>` --> press enter --> move caret to `<p>this is </p><p>m|y</p><p> text</p>` --> click The h3 style.

Comment: I think the most intuitive behaviour would be to break up the P element when a text selection is active. If the cursor just sits with no text selection active then convert the whole block. I understand how to manually do this without breaking up the block programmatically, but I want to spare my users that repetitive chore day after day.

Comment: Sounds logical. Please add that as a suggestion into the CKE dev site and see the replies you get there: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ - You could create a custom style plugin for that. If your styles are hardcoded and there's not too many of them, it doesn't seem very difficult.